# Using grid.edit and grid.remove on grobs saved using ggplotGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I have a complicated `ggplot2` plot made with an home made function (not from me) that I want to reuse in my own plot function.  I want to use the `grid` package to reorganize everything.  I've found this nice tutorial on the old (deprecated) [ggplot wiki](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/editing-raw-grid-objects-from-a-ggplot) but it seems there reproducible example is broken and I can't find the equivalent page on the new wiki page.

Here is my own reproducible example:

I first create a ggplot object that I store (I don't want it printed):

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
dd <- data.frame(x = sample(1:6), y = sample(1:6), cat = c("a","b","a","c","c","b"))

gg <- ggplot(dd, aes(x=x,y=y, color=cat)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

Then, using the `ggplotGrob` function I can extract the `grobs` from my plot:

```
gg_grod <- ggplotGrob(gg)
gg_grod
TableGrob (12 x 11) "layout": 19 grobs
    z         cells       name                                          grob
1   0 ( 1-12, 1-11) background               rect[plot.background..rect.362]
2   5 ( 6- 6, 4- 4)     spacer                                zeroGrob[NULL]
3   7 ( 7- 7, 4- 4)     axis-l           absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.320]
4   3 ( 8- 8, 4- 4)     spacer                                zeroGrob[NULL]
5   6 ( 6- 6, 5- 5)     axis-t                                zeroGrob[NULL]
6   1 ( 7- 7, 5- 5)      panel                      gTree[panel-1.gTree.306]
7   9 ( 8- 8, 5- 5)     axis-b           absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.313]
8   4 ( 6- 6, 6- 6)     spacer                                zeroGrob[NULL]
9   8 ( 7- 7, 6- 6)     axis-r                                zeroGrob[NULL]
10  2 ( 8- 8, 6- 6)     spacer                                zeroGrob[NULL]
11 10 ( 5- 5, 5- 5)     xlab-t                                zeroGrob[NULL]
12 11 ( 9- 9, 5- 5)     xlab-b titleGrob[axis.title.x.bottom..titleGrob.323]
13 12 ( 7- 7, 3- 3)     ylab-l   titleGrob[axis.title.y.left..titleGrob.326]
14 13 ( 7- 7, 7- 7)     ylab-r                                zeroGrob[NULL]
15 14 ( 7- 7, 9- 9)  guide-box                             gtable[guide-box]
16 15 ( 4- 4, 5- 5)   subtitle         zeroGrob[plot.subtitle..zeroGrob.358]
17 16 ( 3- 3, 5- 5)      title            zeroGrob[plot.title..zeroGrob.357]
18 17 (10-10, 5- 5)    caption          zeroGrob[plot.caption..zeroGrob.360]
19 18 ( 2- 2, 2- 2)        tag              zeroGrob[plot.tag..zeroGrob.359]
```

Using the `grid` package, I can now reorganize my layout and redraw some of the `grobs` from my plot:

```
grid.newpage()
grid.rect()
layout1 <- grid.layout(nrow = 3, ncol = 3,
                       heights = unit(1, c("lines", "null", "lines")),
                       widths = unit(1, c("lines", "null", "lines")))
pushViewport(viewport(layout = layout1))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))
grid.draw(gg_grod$grobs[[(1:length(gg_grod$grobs))[gg_grod$layout$name=="panel"]]])
```

Which gives:

[image]

This is good so far, but now I want to extract the legend, modify it (for example, by removing the factor "a" and changing the color of factor "b"), and place in somewhere else on the plot.

I've tried :

```
grid.remove(gg_grod$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[4]])
grid.edit(gg_grod$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[7]], gp=gpar(col="pink"))
```

And it's not working which make sense because `grid.remove` and `grid.edit` requires a `gPath` object.  However, I can't find that path.

Using the example in the ggplot2 wiki, this is suppose to be resolve using the `grid.ls` function, however it seems that the output is now very limited:

```
grid.ls(gg_grod)
layout
```

I can drawthe unmodified legend using:

```
grid.draw(gg_grod$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[1]])
```

[image]

Any idea how to use `grid.remove` and `grid.edit` from a ggplot2 object extracted with `ggplotGrob`?

btw, running the example in the tutorial now gives the error:

```
grid.remove(gPath("GRID.gTree","layout","panel","grill.gTree","panel.grid.major.x.polyline"),grep=T)
Error in removeDLFromGPath(gPath, name, strict, greppath, grepname, global,  : 
  gPath (GRID.gTree::layout::panel::grill.gTree::panel.grid.major.x.polyline) not found
```

P.S.  I don't think it's necessary but I want to put emphasis on the fact that I want to use the `grid` package.  There may be other options and packages to resolve these kind of problems but in my case, I want to use and learn the `grid` package.  My real problem is also more complicated than this trivial example.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use the `grid.edit()` and `grid.remove()` functions? You could just edit the legend by looking into the structures and finding the things you want to edit, for example: 
`legend <- gg_grod$grobs[[15]];
# Make b pink;
legend$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[7]]$gp$col <- "pink";
legend$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[8]]$gp$col <- "pink";
# Remove a;
legend$grobs[[1]]$grobs[3:5] <- list(nullGrob(), nullGrob(), nullGrob())`

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand, your solution works.  If you want to make it as an answer, I'll accept it.  I didn't know the `nullGrob` function and I didn't know you could play directly in the grob object.  Thanks for showing me.